# Match comma separated data-attribute values

Tags: jquery, custom-data-attribute

Need to add class to all of child menu if hover on it's parents menu.

I have the code to add some class to the child menu if I hover on the parent menu by data-id. And this works. But the child menu may have multiple values of parent data-id (data-id="3,2). And I need to add class if I hover on all of it's parents.

```js
$('.menu__list li a[data-id]').hover(function() {
  $('.menu__subcategory li a').addClass('inactive').removeClass('child');
  $('.menu__subcategory li a[data-id=' + $(this).attr('data-id') + ']').addClass('child').removeClass('inactive');
}, function() {
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu__list">
  <li><a href="#" data-id="1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="2">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="3">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu__subcategory">
  <li><a href="#" data-id="1">Submenu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="2">Submenu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="2">Submenu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="3,2">Submenu 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

need to add class if I hover on all child menu with multiple data-id values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make this work you could convert the values you store in the `data` attribute to arrays. Then in the `hover()` function you can use `filter()` to determine if the `id` 
 array of the subcategories `includes()` the parent value which was hovered. Try this:

```js
$('.menu__list li a[data-id]').hover(function() {
  var $aHover = $(this);
  $('.menu__subcategory li a').addClass('inactive').removeClass('child').filter(function() {
    return $(this).data('id').includes($aHover.data('id'));
  }).addClass('child').removeClass('inactive');
}, function() {
  // presumably you've omitted some logic here, or this can be removed.
});
```

```css
.child {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.inactive {
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="menu__list">
  <li><a href="#" data-id="1">Menu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="2">Menu 2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="3">Menu 3</a></li>
</ul>

<ul class="menu__subcategory">
  <li><a href="#" data-id="[1]">Submenu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="[2]">Submenu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="[2]">Submenu 1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" data-id="[3,2]">Submenu 1</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: No problem. Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code

```
$(".menu__subcategory > li a[data-id]").each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));
});

$(".menu__list > li a[data-id]").each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));
});
```

For iterating through all `data-id` attribute, use this:

```
$("a[data-id]").each(function(){
  console.log($(this).attr('data-id'));
});
```

Comment: This doesn't address the question. All it does is tell the OP how to loop through the `a` elements